# Was Hercule Poirot ever wrong?

Tags: poirot

In *Cards on the Table* (S10E02) Hercule Poirot states:

> The question is, can Hercule
> Poirot possibly be wrong?
>
> No one can always be right.
>
> But I am.
>
> Always I am right.
>
> It is so invariable
> it startles me.

Was that right? Has there been any instance, where he made a mistake?

I have seen only a few episodes, and I cannot recall any such occurrence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I presume you are asking about the TV series starring David Suchet, rather than the novels or any other TV or movie versions.

In *The Mysterious Affair at Styles*, (season 3, episode 1)  Hastings  recalls an earlier meeting with Poirot, where murder had occurred, and Hastings was Poirot's suspect for a time.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, as the assertion is from the TV series, the question is primarily targeted at it. Altough the novels' point of view would be interesting too!

Comment: "suspect" doesn't mean Poirot "claims he did it". There's usually several suspects in a case, and usually all but one of them turn out to be not guilty of the murder. Did Poirot state that Hastings did it, or did he merely suspect him?